# Pandas: get column, based on another column which contains column names

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a script to do some pricing. Have a dataframe which contains a quantity list:

| Name | Volume | Area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | 133 | 256 |
| Steel | 55 | 330 |

(and 1800 more lines like those)

What I need to do is create a third column in the df that contains the "true" quantity.
Pretty much, on some materials it's the volume, on others it's the area.

| Name | Volume | Area | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | 133 | 256 | 133 |
| Steel | 55 | 330 | 330 |

So far I've thought to create a dictionary:

my_dict = {'Wood':'Volume', 'Steel':'Area'}

Using map (or replace) I put that into a column in the df:

| Name | Volume | Area | Datafield |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wood | 133 | 256 | Volume |
| Steel | 55 | 330 | Area |

Now, how would I go about putting the quantity into the Quantity column, based on what Datafield says?

I tried

df['Quantity'] = df[df['Datafield']]

But, it crashed and I'm stuck.

Comment: Please provide code to make the DF. A table is almost as useless as an image for [MCVE] purposes

Comment: @MadPhysicist You can `pd.read_clipboard`, no? Though I heard Colab has some problems with it.

Comment: numpy: `df['Qty'] = df.to_numpy()[df.index,df.columns.get_indexer(df['Datafield'])]`

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
df['QTY'] = df.lookup(df.index, df['Datafield'])
```

Alternative:

```
df['QTY'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x['Datafield']],1)
```

Another alternative via melt:

```
k = df.melt('Datafield')
df['QTY'] = k[k.Datafield.eq(k.variable)]['value'].values
```

###### OUTPUT:

```
   Name  Volume  Area Datafield  QTY
0   Wood     133   256    Volume  133
1  Steel      55   330      Area  330
```